# R function efficiency

Tags: r

Any idea for a more efficient implementation of the following function?

```
prod_A_B <- function(A, B, i = NULL, j = NULL) {

  if (is.null(i) & is.null(j)) {
    A * B
  } else if (!is.null(i) & is.null(j)) {
    A[i, ] * B[i, ]
  } else if (!is.null(i) & !is.null(j)) {
    A[i, j] * B[i, j]
  }

}
```

In particular, would it be possible to have a cleaner implementation of the condition statements that would result in a reduced runtime?

Here are some benchmarks:

```
n <- 1e5
d <- 200
A <- matrix(rnorm(n*d), nrow = n, ncol = d)
B <- matrix(rnorm(n*d), nrow = n, ncol = d)

pr1 <- pr2 <- matrix(0, nrow=n, ncol =d)

tm <- microbenchmark(
  {for(i in 1:n) pr1[i,] <- prod_A_B(A, B, i)},
  {for(i in 1:n) pr2[i, ] <- A[i,] * B[i,]}, 
  times=100L)

print(tm)

Unit: milliseconds
       min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 1164.4078 1208.348 1234.607 1224.097 1254.059 1370.098   100
  969.9961 1004.821 1036.738 1021.025 1056.182 1278.767   100
```

The difference is not large given the matrix sizes, but I was still wondering whether I could improve the performance a bit...

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest posting here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for code reviews

Comment: can you `dput` `A`, `B`?

Comment: @SpaceCowboy Ok I will post there too, thanks!

Comment: @Sandipan Dey, sorry the benchmark code chunk was incomplete, it is edited now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save some time by simplifying the logical predicates and also getting rid of multiple function calls as follows:

```
prod2_A_B <- function(A, B, i = NULL, j = NULL) {

  ni <- is.null(i)
  nj <- is.null(j)

  if (ni & nj) {
    A * B
  } else if (nj) { # must be !ni
    A[i, ] * B[i, ]
  } else {         # must be !ni & !nj
    A[i, j] * B[i, j]
  }

}


n <- 1e5
d <- 200
pr1 <- pr2 <- pr <- matrix(0, nrow=n, ncol =d)
A <- matrix(rnorm(n*d), nrow = n, ncol = d)
B <- matrix(rnorm(n*d), nrow = n, ncol = d)
library(microbenchmark)
tm <- microbenchmark(
  {for(i in 1:n) pr1[i,] <- prod_A_B(A, B, i)},
  {for(i in 1:n) pr2[i,] <- prod2_A_B(A, B, i)},
  {for(i in 1:n) pr[i,] <- A[i,] * B[i,]}, 
  times=100L)

print(tm)

Unit: milliseconds
                                           expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
  {for (i in 1:n) pr1[i, ] <- prod_A_B(A, B, i)}  937.9470 944.6690 969.7894 952.2308 964.4701 1390.467   100   c
  {for (i in 1:n) pr2[i, ] <- prod2_A_B(A, B, i)} 898.6802 908.3323 929.7343 914.6826 929.4356 1211.623   100  b 
  {for (i in 1:n) pr[i, ] <- A[i, ] * B[i, ]}     661.2350 666.7071 688.8127 672.6218 679.9028 1005.342   100 a
```